# Quickhull points not returned in correct order

Tags: c#, algorithm, convex

I implemented the quick hull code found on the following page:

http://www.ahristov.com/tutorial/geometry-games/convex-hull.html

The algorithm is returning the correct points of the convex hull, but it is not returning them in the correct trigonometric order. Since the points are in no meaningful order I cannot use them to draw the lines and thus the hull itself.

For example, when I run the algorithm with the following points

```
 (2,5) (9,2) (1,8) (0,5) (3,3)
```

The correct order I want them returned in is:

```
 (0,5) (1,8) (9,2) (3,3)
```

Instead the quick hull algorithm returns them like this:

```
 (1,8) (0,5) (3,3) (9,2)
```

Can anyone please help me

Comment: Since the page you provided is in java, can you post your code, even if it is "exact"?

Comment: Do you want to implement QuickHull exactly or any convex hull algorithm? I mean, the page states that QuickHull is easier to implement than Graham Scan, but I disagree. Graham Scan is not only easier but faster. Here's a JS implementation: http://jsfiddle.net/UbxEM/6/

Comment: Yes I need to implement QuickHull, I've already implemented the others

Answer (score 1):

If it's not possible to modify the algorithm to return them in the correct order, you can compute the [centroid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid) of the returned points (add them all up and divide by the count, the centroid of a convex hull will always lie inside in the hull), then calculate the angle from the centroid to each point like this:

```
point.angle = atan2(point.y - centroid.y, point.x - centroid.x);
```

then sort the list of points based on the angles.

Also, this part of your C# code doesn't match the Java:

```
    // Recursively proceed with new sets
    HullSplit(minPt, farthestPt, leftSetMinPt, ref hull);
    HullSplit(maxPt, farthestPt, leftSetMaxPt, ref hull);
    // should be:
    // HullSplit(farthestPt, maxPt, leftSetMaxPt, ref hull);
```

Java is:

```
    hullSet(A,P,leftSetAP,hull);
    hullSet(P,B,leftSetPB,hull);
```

Also, you have effectively reversed the signs on your point to line tests compared to the Java:

```
public int pointLocation(Point A, Point B, Point P) {
   int cp1 = (B.x-A.x)*(P.y-A.y) - (B.y-A.y)*(P.x-A.x);
   return (cp1>0)?1:-1;
}

if (pointLocation(A,B,p) == -1)  // tests for negative
if (pointLocation(A,P,M)==1) { // tests for positive
if (pointLocation(P,B,M)==1) { // tests for positive
```

C#:

```
private static bool IsAboveLine(Point a, Point b, Point pt)
{
    var result = ((b.X - a.X) * (pt.Y - a.Y))
                -((b.Y - a.Y) * (pt.X - a.X));

    return (result > 0) ? true : false;
}

if (IsAboveLine(minPt, maxPt, pt))  // tests for positive
if (!IsAboveLine(minPt, farthestPt, set.ElementAt(i)))  // tests for negative
if (!IsAboveLine(farthestPt, maxPt, set.ElementAt(i)))  // tests for negative
```

Comment: While that could work that would ultimately increase its time complexity. I'd like a way to have the algorithm return them in the correct order - like my implementation of Graham scan or gift wrapping does

Comment: Is it as simple as changing int insertPosition = hull.indexOf(B); to int insertPosition = hull.indexOf(A); ?

Comment: Seems like I missed that, but it's still the same result